# Problems with boxplots and many zeros

Tags: r, data-visualization, zero-inflation, boxplot

I am having a problem making box plots in R. I have several datasets which measure the vocalization of a species (in "Detection Positive Minutes", the number of times a cetacean was calling per hour) as well as the presence or absence (whether the animal is present or absent in an hour). 
When I try putting this data into R and making box plots, all my data points look like outliers and the boxes are either down completely at zero, or encompass the whole range of values. No useful whiskers anywhere in sight. 
I have attached some pictures.

For example, this is what Detection Positive Minutes look like. 
[image]
And another example, this is what Presence/Absence looks like.
[image]
 I really don't understand the box with no whiskers around "Morning", or why the data is represented by single points for the other times of day (Day, Evening, Night). In fact, there are at least 32 "Present" (=1) observations for "Day", it's just that they are far outnumbered by the 0s, but why is it represented by a single dot, and why does morning have a box around it?
:/
If anyone has any advice, it would be much appreciated! The code I am using is just the simple:
plot(Time, SpeciesPresence)

Comment: You have discovered, empirically, that boxplots are useless for depicting binary data.  Instead, use a way to display the two counts--numbers of zeros and numbers of ones--in each group. Cleveland dot charts and bar plots are good places to start.

Comment: Box plots are problematic with highly skewed data as shown in the top figure.  From all appearances, Almost all of your data is <10 but there is a long tail of outliers out to 60.  Plotting with a log scale on the y-axis will make the boxes look better but can be confusing when making side-by-side comparisons.

Comment: @Dave The problem with the log is that all those boxes show a great many zeros.   Because these are counts, an excellent defaulting starting point is to plot the *square roots.* Doing so consistently will cause no problems for side-by-side comparisons.

Comment: @whuber thank you for the advice! I will try a different way of representing the data. My detection positive minutes are not binary, but do have the same problem of having too many zeros. So for the Presence/Absence I am going to take a look at a Cleveland dot chart, but I am reluctant to transform the data because the following steps I want to take are to model it with a GLM and so since it will not be transformed in the model, I thought it would be confusing to present it as transformed in the visuals.

Comment: In the comment about binary data, whuber was referring to the lower set of boxplots (presence/absence)

Comment: Can you post your data for people to play with? I suspect people would be able to come up with something useful for you.